# Limitar conteúdo HTML em DIVs e distribuir nas seguintes dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando distribuir o conteúdo `HTML(texto,imagens etc)` em  `DIVS` dinamicamente, porém ainda não achei algo relacionado a isso.

Tipo pegar o conteúdo de fora da `DIV` `(overflow)` e inserir na próxima `DIV` Como se fossem páginas.

```js
let texto = `Lorem consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis pariatur ipsum quos, adipisci
    laboriosam expedita possimus soluta tempora culpa, officia rerum ducimus consequuntur delectus
    error cumque maxime aperiam ullam sequi?
    O que é o Lorem Ipsum? O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria
    tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto
    padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma
    misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro.
    Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para a
    tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi
    popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de
    Letraset, que continham passagens`

document.getElementById("page01").innerHTML += texto.substring(0, 305)
document.getElementById("page02").innerHTML += texto.substring(305, 612)
document.getElementById("page03").innerHTML += texto.substring(612, 1000)
```

```css
.page {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page" id="page01">

</div>

<div class="page" id="page02">

</div>
<div class="page" id="page03">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Você pode distribuí-los da seguinte forma!

Somando a quantidade de caracteres e verificar se atingiu o valor **máximo** definido nos parâmetros da função. Pra isso, foi aplicado condições simples..

```js
const loremIpsum = "Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker."; 

const divideTexto = (texto, quantidade) => {
    // verifica se o valor de entrada é menor que 0 ou menor que a quantidade definida, ou seja, não vai rolar nada aqui!
    if (texto.length <= 0 || texto < quantidade)
        return [texto]; // o jeito é retornar o valor total de entrada, pois não condiz com a quantidade total de caracteres.

    var resultado = [], posicao = 0;
    // é criado um array com cada trecho de palavras ["Lorem", "Ipsum", "é", ...]
    var textoSplit = texto.split(/([\s\n\r]+)/);

    // vai percorrer todo o array (textoSplit) criado
    for (var i = 0; i < textoSplit.length; ++i) {
        // instancia a entrada da matriz para uma string vazia caso ela seja null/undefined
        if (!resultado[posicao]) resultado[posicao] = "";
        // soma a quantidade total de caracteres e verifica se atingiu o valor máximo definido.
        if ((resultado[posicao].length + textoSplit[i].length) <= quantidade) {
            // vai armazenando até atingir o valor máximo
            resultado[posicao] += textoSplit[i];
        } else { // caso tenha atingido o valor máximo
            posicao++; // incrementa uma nova posição, ou seja, uma nova chave (página) para o array
        }
    }

    return resultado; // retorna o array com seus respectivos valores
}
```

[teste o código!](https://codepen.io/gleisin-dev/pen/LYyvjEj)

---

### Ótimo, funciona! Porém...

O correto a se fazer (*particularmente falando..*) é particionar/distribuir por **palavras** e não por **quantidade**. Pois pode ocorrer sim de, definir `divideTexto(texto, 100)` e ao atingir a quantidade de 100 caracteres, ser, exatamente a posição do meio de uma palavra, isto é:

> "Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sen" *(100 caracteres)*
>
> > *"... indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem **sendo** utilizado desde o século XVI ..."*

O mesmo sentido de usar `word-break: break-all` do [css](/questions/tagged/css) em parágrafos que por sinal é horrível o resultado, tentando encaixar o maior número possível de caracteres em cada linha. O contrário do `word-wrap: break-word` que quebrará palavras que são muito longas as empurrando para uma nova linha.

---

### Portanto, é mais viável e recomendado..

Distribuí-los por **palavras**, assim, o processo todo ficará mais dinâmico!

```js
const loremIpsum = "Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.";

const dividePalavras = (texto, quantidade) => {
   if (texto.length <= 0 || texto.split(/[\s]+/).length < quantidade) 
      return [texto];
   
   var resultado = [], posicao = 0;
   var textoSplit = texto.split(/([\s\n\r]+)/);
   for (var i = 0; i < textoSplit.length; ++i) {
      if (!resultado[posicao]) resultado[posicao] = "";
      // vai verificar se a quantidade de palavras condiz com a quantidade definida..
      if (resultado[posicao].split(/[\s]+/).length <= quantidade) {
         resultado[posicao] += textoSplit[i]; // vai armazenando até atingir a quantidade total
      } else {
         posicao++; // incrementa uma nova posição, ou seja, uma nova chave (página) para o array
         if (!resultado[posicao]) resultado[posicao] = ""; // // instancia a entrada da matriz para uma string vazia caso ela seja null/undefined
         resultado[posicao] += textoSplit[i]; // para não "engolir" nenhuma palavra, é adicionado para nova posição e assim sucessivamente..
      }
   }
   
   return resultado;
}

// vai mapear todo o array para imprimir os resultados..
dividePalavras(loremIpsum, 25).map(trecho => {
   document.querySelector(".container").innerHTML += `<div class="page">${trecho}</div>`;
});
```

```css
.page {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Muito boa a ideia de separar por palavras, porém notei que a partir da segunda coluna está imprimindo apenas 24 palavras.

Comment: @AndréCabral pronto, corrigido! É porque no `else { posicao++ ...` acabava "engolindo" uma palavra, pois não tinha a condição para validar se é menor ou igual a quantidade definida, por isso o laço só validaria na próxima execução! Boa observação, obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Estou postando apenas como uma referencia. Mas é possível ter um resultado muito similar ao que vc quer apenas com CSS usando `column-count`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vc pode colocar alguns valores como

```
column-count: 3; (define quantas colunas de conteúdo vc quer)
column-rule: 1px solid black; (define a linaha entre uma coluna e outra)
column-gap: 40px; (define o espaçamento entre uma coluna e outra)
```

Segue o exemplo fazendo u `innerHTML` do texto na `div`. Então mesmo o texto sendo injetado dinâmicamente o resultado é bem satisfatório, e a responsividade é super fácil de ajustar mudando o valor do `column-count` para **2** ou **1** em telas pequenas.

```js
let texto = `Lorem consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis pariatur ipsum quos, adipisci
    laboriosam expedita possimus soluta tempora culpa, officia rerum ducimus consequuntur delectus
    error cumque maxime aperiam ullam sequi?
    O que é o Lorem Ipsum? O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria
    tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto
    padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma
    misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro.
    Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para a
    tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi
    popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de
    Letraset, que continham passagens`

document.getElementById("page01").innerHTML += texto
```

```css
div {
  column-count: 3;
  column-rule: 1px solid black;
  column-gap: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page01">

</div>
```

Comment: Muito bom hugocsl! cogitei também o uso do `column-count` utilizando apenas [tag:css] porém devido a tag [tag:javascript] presente, ai priorizei! Mas muito bom mesmo a referência!

Answer (score 1):

você pode, antes de inserir as divs, calcular quantas seriam criadas. Após isso, inserir dinamicamente a div no html com a sua respectiva posição de texto.

```js
let texto = `Lorem consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis pariatur ipsum quos, adipisci
    laboriosam expedita possimus soluta tempora culpa, officia rerum ducimus consequuntur delectus
    error cumque maxime aperiamor cumque maxime aperiam ullam sequi?
    O que é o Lorem Ipsum? O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria
    tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto
    padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma
    misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro.
    Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para a
    tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi
    popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de
    Letraset, que continham passagensor cumque maxime aperiam ullam sequi?
    O que é o Lorem Ipsum? O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria
    tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto
    padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma
    misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro.
    Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para a
    tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi
    popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de
    Letraset, que continham passagensor cumque maxime aperiam ullam sequi?
    O que é o Lorem Ipsum? O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria
    tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto
    padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma
    misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro.
    Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para a
    tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi
    popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de
    Letraset, que continham passagens ullam sequi?
    O que é o Lorem Ipsum? O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da indústria
    tipográfica e de impressão. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto
    padrão usado por estas indústrias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma
    misturou os caracteres de um texto para criar um espécime de livro.
    Este texto não só sobreviveu 5 séculos, mas também o salto para a
    tipografia electrónica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi
    popularizada nos anos 60 com a disponibilização das folhas de
    Letraset, que continham passageor cumque maxime aperiam ullam sequi?
    O que é o Lorem Ipsum? O Lorem Ipsum é um texto modelo da  
`
    
var countText = Math.ceil(texto.length / 305)
var elemento = document.querySelector(".container")


for (var c=1; c <= countText; c++) {
  
  elemento.innerHTML += `
    <div class="page">
        ${texto.substring(305*(c-1), 305*c)}
    </div>
 `
}
```

```css
.page {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Então, essa forma eu até pensei porém o problema está na quebra dos textos, essa soluçao dependendo da posição quebra a palavra ao meio, assim como está no seu código.

Comment: O problema também é se tiver tags (por ex., de imagem, tipo `<img src="imagem.jpg">`). Dessa forma aí não vai funcionar.